# Powered USB 3.0 (USB3) Hub with individual switches that delivers USB3 speed to each port

Tags: usb, hub

I purchased a [powered USB 3 Hub with individual switches](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B07CQQDYQZ).

It appears to meet all these criteria:

- Must have external power source
- 3-5 ports total (keep it small)
- Individual toggle switches for each port
- USB3 speeds for all ports

Unfortunately, when actually using it, it doesn't deliver USB3 speeds beyond port 1.  See [this Super User SE question](https://superuser.com/questions/1344522/should-all-drives-on-a-usb-3-0-usb3-hub-be-the-same-speed).

So I'm looking for a powered USB3 hub that actually is confirmed to deliver USB3 speeds for all ports.

(Note this is different from a similar question in which the external power is optional... it is a requirement here.)